# Django formset not valid

Tags: django, forms, validation, pdf, error-handling

I have a Django website, and on one of the pages there is form which users can use to enter details about a presentation for a specific project. A project can have multiple presentations (each presentation is for an individual budget for that project), but only one of the presentations will be for the 'current' budget (i.e. the currently 'accepted' budget).

There is the functionality to upload a 'PDF package' for the budget for each presentation- this is done by clicking a 'Choose File' button on the form, selecting the PDF to upload using the dialog box that opens, and clicking the 'Upload' button on the form. Once done, a 'PDF' icon is displayed in the place where the 'Choose File' button was displayed, and clicking this icon opens a new tab in the browser, in which a preview of the PDF file is displayed.

I am now trying to add a second button to the form to allow the user to upload a 'drawing' file (which is likely to also be a PDF file) to the form.

I have the 'Choose file' button in place on the form, and clicking it opens up a dialog which allows the user to select the file. Once they have selected the file, the filename is displayed next to the button, so the file has been added to the form, ready to be uploaded to the database when the user clicks the 'Upload' button.

On clicking the 'Upload' button, all of the information entered in the form, including the PDF file and drawing file should be added to that project budget in the database.

However, although this 'Upload' button was working when it was just uploading the original PDF package file, it seems to have broken since I have added the 'drawings' file to the form. If I click 'Upload' with only a PDF attached to the form, it works, but if I click 'Upload' when I have a 'drawing' file attached to the form, the file is not uploaded, and my console displays some output saying:

> ('Drawing formset not valid.', [])

I know that this output is coming from the view that's being used to upload the PDF package and drawing to the form (it is the output of some error handling that I have added to the `view`, but I'm not sure why/ what is causing this error handling code to be run... The view for uploading the PDFs & drawings to the form is defined with:

```
def upload_budget_pdfs(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    print("Value of project in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", project)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
        print("Value of presentations in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", presentations)
        drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))

        print("Value of drawing_formset in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", drawing_formset)

        if drawing_formset.is_valid():
        #if drawing_formset != None:
            print 'Saving drawing_formset'
            print "Before", [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
            for drawing_form in drawing_formset: #ERF(24/01/2017 @ 1610) This line is what's causing the MultiValueDictKeyError
                if drawing_form.instance.budget:
                    print 'Instance', drawing_form.instance.budget
                    drawing = drawing_form.save(commit=False)
                    drawing.budget = drawing_form.instance.budget
                    drawing.save()
                print drawing, [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
        else: 
            print("Drawing formset not valid.", drawing_formset.errors)


        budget_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project, prefix="presentations")

        if budget_formset.is_valid() and budget_formset.has_changed():
            updated_budget_presentations = budget_formset.save()
        elif budget_formset.has_changed(): print 'Budget formset not valid.',budget_formset.errors

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects:concept', args=[project_id]))
```

So the reason I'm getting this error in the console is because the `else` clause of the `if` statement: `if drawing_formset.is_valid():` is what is being run.

As shown in the `view` above, `drawing_formset` is defined with:

```
drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))
```

and `DrawingUploadFormset` is defined in the `forms.py` file for this app, with:

```
class DrawingUploadForm(ValidatedForm):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Drawing
        fields = ['pdf',]

DrawingUploadFormset = modelformset_factory(Drawing, form=DrawingUploadForm, max_num=12, extra=1, can_delete=False)
```

I don't understand why the statement `if drawing_formset.is_valid():` is returning `false`... can anyone explain this to me? Is there something I'm doing wrong in how I'm declaring/ using `drawing_formset`? There don't appear to be any errors when evaluating this `if` statement, as the `print` statement is just showing an empty array `[]` where `drawing_formset.errors` would be displayed... and yet somehow the `if` statement is evaluating to `false`... Why is this?

**EDIT**

Ok, so I made the edit to the definition of `drawing_formset`, as suggested, and this line is now:

```
drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST.get('drawings'), request.FILES, prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))
```

I narrowed down that the error appears to be coming from the line `for drawing_form in drawing_formset:`, and have surrounded this with a `try-catch`, to see if I can find exactly what the issue is. This part of the code now looks like this:

```
try:
    for drawing_form in drawing_formset: #ERF(24/01/2017 @ 1610) This line is what's causing the MultiValueDictKeyError
        print 'for loop entered in upload_budget_pdfs() - line 1034 '
        if drawing_form.instance.budget:
            drawing = drawing_form.save(commit=False)
            drawing.budget = drawing_form.instance.budget
            drawing.save()
        print drawing, [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
    except Exception as e:
        print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
```

and this is displaying the following output in the console:

> ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with ()

This is the first time I have seen an error message like this, and have no idea what it means, or how to resolve it... anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I've marked the given answer as 'accepted' as this was part of the solution, and pointed me in the right direction for finding the full solution.

In case anyone else has a similar issue, I will add that to get this fully working, I needed to include the `drawing_formset` variable in my template.

I did this by nesting the following inside the relevant HTML tag:

```
<tr>
    {% if not forloop.last %}
        <td colspan="3"><label>Budget PDF package</label></td>
    {% endif %}

    <td colspan="3"><label>Drawings</label></td>
    <!-- Need to include the formset in the template -->
    {{ drawing_formset.as_table }} 
    {{ drawing_formset.management_form }}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't passed any POST data to DrawingUploadFormset.

Comment: I tried changing its definition to: `drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))`, but when I now try to submit the form, having upload a PDF file as a drawing, I get an error page that says: `MultiValueDictKeyError at /projects/6215/upload-budget-pdf/`, and the traceback appears to indicate that the line `if drawing_formset.is_valid():` is what's causing the error... I don't understand what's wrong with this...?

Comment: Ah, ok, it seems I should be using `request.POST.get()` - which I have changed it to, but now get a `TypeError` that says: `get() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`... I can't see how I've given it one argument already, as I just used empty parenthesis... but presumably this means I should be passing a parameter to it, I'm just not sure what I should be passing to it... Any ideas?

Comment: What are you talking about? Where did you use `.get()`, and why? And isn't this exactly the same problem you asked about a couple of weeks ago?

Comment: I used `.get()` in the declaration of `drawing_formset` inside the view- which is what the error message was complaining about not being valid, i.e.   `drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST.get(), request.FILES, prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))`. I used it because you suggested I wasn't passing any POST data to `DrawingUploadFormset`- I'm just not sure what I need to pass to its parameters...?

Comment: You don't pass parameters **because you don't do this**. What could have made you think you should?

Comment: The answer to another question that I found on SO when researching how to solve the issue...

Comment: So when you say I should be passing POST data to `DrawingUploadFormset`, how/ where should I be doing that?

Comment: I've edited my OP to show that I'm now using `request.POST.get()`... I've also added some error handling to my code, and this is producing output in the console that says: `ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with ()`... any ideas what this means?

Comment: Ah- I was missing the reference to the `formset` in my template. I've updated my OP to show what else I needed to do after following your answer. Thanks for the help- got me looking in the right place...